# python indexed variables not returning correct result when run through a function but when entered separately returns correct result

Tags: python, math, indexing

I'm building a roller coaster design tool and working on the coordinate system. The structure for 2 lines next to each other is basically set up so the the user will have to only enter a distance for the control point and the x,y,z coordinates for the end point. the control points between the 2 and the end point of the first line must all be aligned for the curve to be smooth. to make it easier to design the track spine I set up the coordinate structure to take the control point as a distance so the point can be calculated later when ever thing gets rendered.
here is my coordinate system :

```py
coordinates =[[x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,x3,y3,z3],
             [d,x3,y3,z3]]
```

the first point will have all the coordinates in it as calculation for the points will begin on the second curve and there is no need to specify the start point as it is the same as the end point of the previous line. here is the code i've currently got to regenerate the coordinates for list after the start list :

```py
def point(c,s,d):
  return (c + c - s) * d

cordinates = [[0,0,5,5,5,5,10,10,5],
              [7,13,56,8]]

for i in range(1,len(cordinates)):
  try :
    distance = cordinates[i][0]
    end_x,end_y,end_z = cordinates[i][1],cordinates[i][2],cordinates[i][3]
    cordinates[i].clear()

    control_x = point(cordinates[i-1][6],cordinates[i-1][3],distance)
    control_y = point(cordinates[i-1][7],cordinates[i-1][4],distance)
    control_z = point(cordinates[i-1][8],cordinates[i-1][5],distance)
    
    cordinates[i].append(cordinates[i-1][6])
    cordinates[i].append(cordinates[i-1][7])
    cordinates[i].append(cordinates[i-1][8])
    cordinates[i].append(control_x)
    cordinates[i].append(control_y)
    cordinates[i].append(control_z)
    cordinates[i].append(end_x)
    cordinates[i].append(end_y)
    cordinates[i].append(end_z)
    
  except IndexError :
    pass
```

but for some reason the point function works when i put the inputs in separately but when its in the code it generates really far out results it might be my indexing but i've looked at it and it seems fine to me but I might be missing something obvious, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I suspect i is never different from 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so after some further debugging I have found that the formula i was using is incorrect by removing d and just having it as

```py
def point(c,s):
  return (c + c - s)
```

then it works fine I will now look into having the point be any where on the line